# Getting back to the original selector in chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

If I have a statement like this:

```
$('a:first').parent().next().css('color', 'red');
```

How do I get back to the original jQuery object `$('a:first')`?

People are suggesting `end()` but it  only travels back 1 step, I want to get all the way to the first part of the chain.

**EDIT:** Okay, so the reason I want this is because this expression does not work:

```
$(this).parent().remove().next().show();
```

Comment: I'm confused .. what are you trying to do?  If you need `$('a:first')` can't you just do `$('a.first').doit()` again?

Comment: Based on that, I recommend @meagar's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "store" `a:first`, and then apply additional selectors to it without losing it, you should *store* it:

```
var $firstA = $('a:first');

$firstA.parent().next().css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: You're not going to find a simpler or faster solution. You shouldn't be traversing all over the DOM with `end` or `addBack` calls to reach an element you've already selected.

Comment: Gah, this is indeed the most efficient and correct answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of in this case is using `.end()` twice:

```
$('a:first').parent().next().css('color', 'red').end().end()
```

While this doesn't look very nice, it works as you need, and you'll need to use it for every step back you want. Unfortunately jQuery doesn't have method like `.endAll()` to get you back to the original selector, so you can do what meagar suggested and save the original one on a variable...

Comment: Yeah I thought about this solution too but then I have to keep track of how many objects I've got on the stack. Is there somewhere I can suggest to the jQuery developers for them to add an endAll function to the core?

Comment: @silkfire No, because this is a *solved problem*. Any time you think you need an `endAll()` it's because you're not just storing your originally selected elements in a variable for repeated reference. You're *meant* to cache your selected elements in this way, if you want to use them repeatedly.